# How to divide query results into pages?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, grouping

I want to implement a "page" system so that in the first page I show 10 results (1-10), in the 2nd page I show the other 10 (11-20) results. etc.

The results should be ordered in different ways, for example `ORDER BY count DESC;`
Is there a pure MySQL solution for this, like

```
$results_per_page = 10;
$page_number = $_GET['page'];

mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY count DESC 
LIMIT $results_per_page*$page , $results_per_page*($page+1) // Of course, I made up this line
;");
```

Comment: What you're trying to do is called paging. And you need to stop using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: Thanks. And why not mysql_ functions? And what should I use instead?

Comment: See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @marvin I myself prefer [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @Blazemonger why, and what is the difference?

Comment: mysql_ is potentially insecure, and doesn't have a lot of modern mysql functionality, being designed for 3.23, which is ...out of date.

Comment: ok, thanks everybody. Now I have to change millions of lines of code :D

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question, I should select them like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY whatever DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;
```

for the 2nd page.

so with the variables it becomes

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY whatever DESC LIMIT $results_per_page OFFSET $page_number-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

After cleaning the $page variable, since you should never accept input straight from the user for security reasons, you should do this:

```
<?php
$first = $results_per_page * ($page-1); // on page 1 you want to start at row 0
$querystring = "SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY count DESC 
LIMIT $first, $results_per_page";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. And what do you exactly mean by "cleaning" the variable?

Comment: If you're using mysql_ functions (which you shouldn't do), run mysql_real_escape_string($page) to make sure it's query-safe. Whatever you decide to use for your DB access, make sure you use it to prepare $page for use.

Answer (score 0):

```
make a function passing four parameters
function getresult($index,$order,$start,$no_rows)
 {

    $sql="SELECT * FROM mytable order by $index $orders limit $start,$no_rows";
 }
```

where,

$index=on which sorting u want to do

$order=asc/desc

$start=from on yow will start to get records

$no_$rows=you want to get no of rows